# Using Bootstrap with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have finished a small web app wiht Node.js.
But i can't upload this thing yet because it looks so ugly!
I am trying to prettify it with Bootstrap.

Having never worked with it before, i have some trouble getting it started. I downloaded the Bootstrap and unzip it into my public folder. So it now contains the folders [images, css, js]. Is this how it is supposed to be?

Then one of my ejs files contained this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Because i had initially based this from an online template.
So now i guess this line has to change to point to my locally installed bootstrap files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded bootstrap, then there's no need to use CDN. Just upload all the bootstrap with your website and include them in your html file with relative paths, read more here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, you could still point to the CDN.

Anyway, if you want to install it you can do it through `npm` or any other package manager:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Read about the differences [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096974/using-bootstrap-with-node-js).